# Where is firebase data center located ?

Tags: firebase

We are defining our privacy policy and customers (specially in the EU) are concerned where their data is located. 
Is this still the right answer or did anything change since 2014?

http://grokbase.com/t/gg/firebase-talk/14axy4z42p/firebase-where-is-my-data-stored

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the Google DevFest in Amsterdam, I heard from Frank van Puffelen who presented Firebase to us that at that time (10/10/2015) they had a datacentre in the US and were planning to open one in Europe.

I'd like to give you more details but that's all I know.

I'm also hoping they will open a datacentre in the EU, since there are fresh laws about where our data collected from EU citizens can be stored and that the Safe Harbour legislation will become irrelevant from what I understand (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: I asked this question again at the Google DevFeest in Amsterdam (2016 edition this time) but I didn't get an answer from the presenters.

Answer (score 0):

**According to the [official FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy/#data_storage_and_processing_locations)**, there are certain services that are US-Only.

For example, these are **US-Only**:

- Firebase Realtime Database
- Cloud Firestore for Firebase

The rest of the services are claimed **Global**, and can be hosted in any Google data center, or even a data center run by a selected external party. E.g.:

- Cloud Storage for Firebase
- Cloud Functions for Firebase

---

The FAQ also mentions, that Firestore will soon become available Globally:

> Note: Though currently US-only, Cloud Firestore will soon be available at all Google Cloud Platform locations.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Google guide [Set a project location](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/locations), you can either choose for a **multi-regional location** or a **regional location**. **Multi-regional locations** offer better replication over multiple regions and better write latency, but are only available in the US (as of writing). **Regional locations** keep your data within the region, but that means that if that region experiences e.g. a power outage, your service will become unavailable. However, for **regional locations**, a data center in Frankfurt, Germany is available (again, as of writing).

**Side-Note:** Cloud Firestore and Cloud Storage will be within the specified region, but Cloud Functions will always be in `us-central1` (as of writing).